# React JS : How can I compare values of two different fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to javascript and reactjs . SO any help I can get will be really appreciated.

I have two date fields (start date, and end date) inside a render method. How can I access the values of these date filelds and validate that end date is after the start date.

I cannot figure out how to access the values of the date fields.
Here is my code :

```
const renderDates= (value) =>
 {
    //Do something
 }
  return
  {
    <React.Fragment>
       <Field
          component = {Datepicker}
           name = "sdate"
            id = "date 1"
             label = "sdate"
             onChage = {handleDate1}
        />
        <Field
          component = {Datepicker}
           name = "edate"
            id = "date 2"
             label = "edate"
             onChage = {handleDate2}
        />
    </React.Fragment>

   };

let handleDate1 = (value) =>
{
    //Access sdate 
};

 let handleDate2 = (value) =>
{
    //Access edate 
};
```

Q: But how do I compare the values of sdate to edate ?

Thank you

Comment: `value.target.value`? you can `console.log(value)` you will have there some value

Comment: I think your above code will crash. you can't have `return` and the contents of return on a new line in javascript. It looks like you're trying to follow a C#  convention for braces, but you're gonna run into issues also no one else codes like that in javascript. take a look at prettier for a more standard js style https://prettier.io/

Answer (score 1):

React data-flow allows you passing data from parent component to children. You can use callbacks to send data from the child component to the parent component.

We can use state and controlled components to manage state in parent component and compare values.

So, in your case you can solve your problem in such way:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state={svalue: new Date(), evalue: new Date() }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.svalue.getTime() === this.state.evalue.getTime()) {
      // they are equal
    }
  }
  renderDates = (value) =>
   {
    //Do something
    return
    {
      <React.Fragment>
         <Field
            component = {Datepicker}
            value={this.state.svalue}
            name = "sdate"
            id = "date 1"
            label = "sdate"
            onChage = {handleDate1}
          />
          <Field
            component = {Datepicker}
            value={this.state.evalue}
            name = "edate"
            id = "date 2"
            label = "edate"
            onChage = {handleDate2}
          />
      </React.Fragment>

     };

  handleDate1 = (value) => {
      this.setState({svalue: value});
  };

  handleDate2 = (value) => {
      this.setState({evalue: value});
  };

}
```

You can read a bit more about controlled components here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components